# Can I set the default isolation level for sql?

Tags: sql, go

I can set isolation level with a transaction using sql.TxOptions. So I would like to know any way I can configure the isolation for Query, Exec.

---

Update: To be more precise, I am asking how to set the isolation level for connections like jdbc. The answer I have now is adding params to the database url.

Comment: What database and driver are you using?

Comment: This is a question for your database, more than for the language.